# Corona SDK, do I need to pay for it?

Tags: lua, corona-sdk

I'm a single dev making simple mobile games.  I was looking at corona sdk for my next project.  I don't understand what the difference between the paid version and the free version is. It seems that the whole SDK is free, so what does the paid version give you that the free version doesnt?  I've been reading through the site, but I'm not quite getting it.

I will need to interface with apple's game center etc.. is that not accessible to me without paying?

Comment: I haven't used Corona in years, but I developed one iOS game with it; back then you couldn't release a game with the free version, no idea if that's still the case.

Answer (score 1):

There were several major changes in Corona pricing model throughout its history. As of now (since March 1, 2015) Corona SDK is completely free for use. The major difference from paid models is no support for Native libraries. However there is no guarantee it won't become paid again or, more generally, if it will be available at all. This is a major drawback of this platform which you must consider. I personally felt it's too risky to invest time into this platform.